# Typescript на Backend

Tags: node.js, typescript

Смотрел требования в вакансии и увидел следующее: понимание почему не нужен typescript и прочие транспиляторы на backend части проекта. Собственно не могу понять, почему не нужен typescript на backend.

Comment: Причина очень проста - вакансии иногда составляют люди, которые считают что их мнение - единственно правильное.

Comment: А почему ты считаешь, что он там нужен?

Comment: Typescript привносит статическую типизацию, сильную причём. Мне, например, на нем проще писать нежели на чистом js. Я чётко понимаю что за тип, с которым я работаю. Вдобавок мне нравится ооп. В js в общем то даже инкапсуляции нет, как таковой. Ts даёт много разных полезностей на тему ООП. Интерфейсы, модификаторы доступа к членам класса и прочее.

Comment: Ну, пара причин, которые я вижу:
1. Удлинение срока разработки (однако сокращает срок дебага), тут спорная причина, ибо на чистом js потом слишком много средств и времени на дебаг будут уходить, также зависит от направленности проектов, если это какие-то мини проекты, тогда это ts того не стоит.
2. Больше возможностей оптимизации, если сверх нагруженный проект.